# Where am I going wrong? Trying to print no of times number is added before returning single digit

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function AdditivePersistence(num) {
    var count = 0;
    while (num.toString().length > 1) {
        count++;
        var num = calcVal(num);

    }
    return count;

    function calcVal(str) {
        var sum = 0;
        var arr = str.toString().split("");
        for (var i of arr) {
            sum = sum + arr[i];
        }
        return parseInt(sum.toString());
    }
}

console.log(AdditivePersistence(2233));
```

`calcValue` function returns sum of the array numbers and while loop repeats until returned number length is 1.

Comment: When you iterate an array using a `for...of` loop, `i` is a value from the array not the index.  Also, in your `while` loop you have this: `var num ....` you're declaring a new variable instead of using the one passed to the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use for...of, `i` is the digit and not the index of the digit. In addition you need to parse the digit.

```
  sum = sum + parseInt(i, 10); // i is the number, not the index
```

Since you used `i` as an index, the result of `calcVal()` was always a string of length > 2, which means an infinite loop in your case.

**Fixed code:**

```js
function AdditivePersistence(num) {
  var count = 0;
  
  while (num.toString().length > 1) {
    count++;
    num = calcVal(num);
  }
  
  return count;

  function calcVal(str) {
    var sum = 0;
    var arr = str.toString().split("");

    for (var i of arr) {
      sum = sum + parseInt(i, 10); // i is the number, not the index
    }
    
    return sum;
  }
}

console.log(AdditivePersistence(2233));
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the corrections ! Why do we need to parseInt "i" in for..of when the array elements are already numbers?

Comment: They are not numbers because - `var arr = str.toString().split("");` returns an array of strings.